# Vtk - world coordinates at mouse pos

Tags: python, qt, opengl, pyqt, vtk

Is there a possibility to get the world coordinates by the mouse-position in the rendering window on the x-z plane (y=0)?

Answer (score 2):

That should be possible, but maybe some calculations are required.
I would start out with this [this example](https://vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Boneyard/Cxx/Interaction/ClickWorldCoordinates). Grab a mouse event like mouse move or mouse click and use `vtkCoordinate` to transform this into world coordinates.

From the example (not python but should be enough to get the idea across):

```
virtual void OnLeftButtonDown() 
    {
      std::cout << "Pressed left mouse button." << std::endl;
      int x = this->Interactor->GetEventPosition()[0];
      int y = this->Interactor->GetEventPosition()[1];
      std::cout << "(x,y) = (" << x << "," << y << ")" << std::endl;
      vtkSmartPointer<vtkCoordinate> coordinate = 
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkCoordinate>::New();
      coordinate->SetCoordinateSystemToDisplay();
      coordinate->SetValue(x,y,0);

      // This doesn't produce the right value if the sphere is zoomed in???
      double* world = coordinate->GetComputedWorldValue(this->Interactor->GetRenderWindow()->GetRenderers()->GetFirstRenderer());
      std::cout << "World coordinate: " << world[0] << ", " << world[1] << ", " << world[2] << std::endl;

      // Forward events
      vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera::OnLeftButtonDown();
    }
```

Now when you obtained the world coordinates at click you probably need to calculate the intersection of the line cameraposition to mouseposition (in the world) and where it intersects the x-z plane.

Answer (score 1):

I can kind of reproduce it with [vtkplotter](https://github.com/marcomusy/vtkplotter):

```py
from vtkplotter import datadir, Plotter, Point
import vtk

def onLeftClick(mesh):
    vcr = vtk.vtkCoordinate()
    vcr.SetCoordinateSystemToDisplay()
    pt = vcr.GetComputedWorldValue(vp.renderer)
    vp.add(Point(mesh.picked3d, c='red'))
    vp.add(Point(pt, c='white'))
    vp.renderer.ResetCamera()
    print(mesh.picked3d, pt)

vp = Plotter(verbose=0)
vp.load(datadir+"bunny.obj")
vp.mouseLeftClickFunction = onLeftClick
vp.show()
```

but i'm not sure if that's the desired output

[image]